# QAF | Configure multiple Remote.server for the single multi driver run Mobile to Web and back

Tags: selenium, webdriver, qaf

I have to switch drivers between the run to 2 different service providers in the same testcase/scenario.

Presently I'm using "env.resources" to set multiple Env details in different files, but "remote.server" in the 2nd env file always takes over.

Eg:

Web Test: BrowserStack | Appium/App Test: ExperiTest

I have referred following post, which talks predominantly about switching drivers but not multiple remote.server/port

[Switch back and forth between drivers (across different environment) in qmetry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68586003/switch-back-and-forth-between-drivers-across-different-environment-in-qmetry)

[Multiple OS, browsers for parallel execution using Saucelabs and QAF framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042047/multiple-os-browsers-for-parallel-execution-using-saucelabs-and-qaf-framework)

[QAF - How to automate both WEB and MOBILE app using QAF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65796689/qaf-how-to-automate-both-web-and-mobile-app-using-qaf)

https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/qaf-2.1.13/properties_list.html

According to the below link, we can set up multiple environments, but how can I pass the env details during the run via switchDriver

https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/managing_resources_for_different_env.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set "remote.server" using getBundle before calling the switchDriver or testBase

```
getBundle().setProperty("remote.server","Remote server URL");

switchDriver("chromeRemoteDriver"); // Common step from QAF
(or)
QAFTestBase testBase = getTestBase(); //TestBaseProvider.instance().get()
testBase.setDriver("chromeRemoteDriver");
```

Comment: You also can take benefit of [driver resources](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/managing_resources_for_different_env.html#managing-driver-specific-resource)